# APACHE PHP вывести список файлов из монтированного каталога

Tags: php, apache, glob

Пытаюсь в Cent OS 7 вывести список файлов в hml (вот кусок PHP скрипта):

```
foreach (glob('/mnt/windows/*.*') as $file)
```

результат - пусто, каталог точно не пустой

Причем вот так работает:

```
foreach (glob('/var/www/*.*') as $file)
```

А вот так уже нет, даже если в каталоге VAR есть файлы:

```
foreach (glob('/var/*.*') as $file)
```

Права на каталог mnt и windows у пользователя apache есть..
3 часа гуглил, но ничего не нагуглил, может кто сталкивался?

Comment: Логи посмотреть религия не позволяет?

Comment: Благодарю за время, которое вы уделили моему вопросу, но в /var/log/httpd/error_log не нашел ошибок, связанных с данной темой

Comment: @Maxim, учитывайте что может накладываться и "проблема" с правами, и "проблема" с wildcards. Думаю из-за этого у вас в /var/www работает, а в /var/ не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Права не разрешат это сделать.

Но если выставить на места монтирования соответствующие права для вебсервера, то в этом случае получится. А без этого будет ситуация описанная ниже.

```
$dircontent = scandir ('/media/xuser/466/');
var_dump($dircontent);
exit;
```

Получаем ошибку `Permission denied` потому что apach`и не должны лазить где попало.

[image: Permission denied]

---

**дописываю:** Если с правами всё в порядке, то это из-за неправильного использования символов-... (забыл как на русс правильно) **wildcards**.

```
$dircontent1 = glob('/media/*');    //выводит всё что попадает под этот шаблон
$dircontent2 = glob('/media/.*');   //выводит только скрытые файлы и папки
$dircontent3 = glob('/media/*.*');  //файлы с расширением (+папки в имени которых есть точка)
var_dump($dircontent1,$dircontent2,$dircontent3);
exit;
```

---

```
    /var/www/html/oop/html/index.php:10:
    array (size=1)
    0 => string '/media/xuser' (length=12)

    /var/www/html/oop/html/index.php:10:
    array (size=4)
    0 => string '/media/.' (length=8)
    1 => string '/media/..' (length=9)
    2 => string '/media/.directory' (length=17)
    3 => string '/media/.hidden' (length=14)

    /var/www/html/oop/html/index.php:10:
    array (size=0)
    empty
```

---

```
xuser@mbs:~$ ls -la /media/
итого 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  52 ноя 26 22:12 .
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root 293 ноя 13 21:09 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  45 мая 24  2020 .directory -> /etc/kubuntu-default-settings/directory-media
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root  42 мая 24  2020 .hidden -> /etc/kubuntu-default-settings/hidden-media
drwxr-x---+  4 root root  27 ноя 24 20:08 xuser
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я предварительно вчера давал все права на каталог куда монтированы windows данные. Но вашим методом все равно попробовал проверить, результат выводится как array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "." [1]=> string(2) ".."

Comment: Т.е. получается уже ближе к истине, апач видит каталог /mnt/windows/ но получается не видит файлы, которые в нем находятся, хотя они там точно есть

Comment: @Maxim, я дополнил ответ.