# Как вывести список файлов по маске?

Tags: php, php7, файловая-система

Собственно, нужно вывести список файлов по маске без директорий в этом списке и без ". и .."
Также поиск не должен искать в поддерикториях!!!

Comment: Пример маски: "*2.2.18*.exe"

Comment: и что у вас тут маска?

Comment: @teran ой, видно на сайте звездочки в комментах не отображаются... Короче, после 18 и перед точкой должна быть звездочка

Comment: гляньте сюда 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1223806/apache-php-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$files = array();
$dir = '/SlimPage/www/DWAKU2';

foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) {
    if (is_file($file)) {
        $files[] = basename($file); 
    }
} 

print_r($files);
?>
```